# EF Core insert data by ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project where I want to insert new members by using an api call.

This call will be a post call.

The class I want to insert is the Member class

```
public partial class Member
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MemberId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public int GuildRankId { get; set; }
    public int? MainMemberId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClassId")]
    public virtual Class Class { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GuildRankId")]
    public virtual Rank GuildRank { get; set; }
    public virtual Member? MainMember { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Guildevent> EventsJoined { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("MainMember")]
    public virtual ICollection<Member>? InverseMainMember { get; set; }
}
```

The problem that I am having is that when a user tries to add a new member by posting a member object. I want it to match the foreign relation ships by Id.

For example, someone tries to add a new user by the name of "Eric", with the `ClassId` of 8 and a guild rank id of 13. When you post this data to the `AddMember` action. You get an error that the `Guildrank` and `Class` are required fields. This is of course correct because every member need to have these.

I tried to circumvent this by doing it manually in the method before saving the data to the tables like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Member>> PostMember(Member member)
{
    member.Class = _context.Classes.First(c => c.ClassId == member.ClassId);
    member.GuildRank = _context.Ranks.First(c => c.GuildRankId == member.GuildRankId);

    _context.Members.Add(member);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetMember", new { id = member.MemberId }, member);
}
```

However I still get this error. It looks like the written code isn't even reached and the error is thrown because the Member model is incorrect.

Is there anyway I can either disable this check, or preferably find the foreign relationships by the defined ID's automatically as part of EF?

When I check the database, I can confirm that all relations are correct.

Comment: Going to need more info because something else is going on here, simply setting the `FK` property in the `Entity` should work. So I don't see anything wrong with your code if you simply do: `_context.Members.Add(member)` without retrieving the `Class` or `GuildRank` from the db first. Provided that `member.ClassId` and `member.GuildRankId` are not null, it seems to me like they are probably not correct.

Comment: Inspect the member values within your post call to ensure all fields are being populated the way your expect. Controller methods written to accept "entities" are not actually getting entities, they are getting form data or AJAX JSON that they are casting to an Entity contract. This is a huge misnomer that trips up new developers and exposes your system to unintended tampering. Data for inserts or updates should be named/typed for what they are: AddMemberRequest / UpdateMemberRequest, not Member entities.